# LVTTL Buffer IC output logic when input is high and not connected to supply voltage

Tags: buffer, texas-instruments

To buffer a LVTTL signal to FPGA I am using this TI buffer [SN74ALVCH16827DGGR](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74alvch16827.pdf?ts=1614570394899&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fstore%252Fti%252Fen%252Fp%252Fproduct%252F%253Fp%253DSN74ALVCH16827DGGR).The buffer IC is placed on a FMC based IO card mated to a ZYNQ mother card. The problem I am facing here is when an input signal is applied to the buffer IC, there is an output signal even when there is no power supply to this IC. The output enable signals are connected to PCB GND.
I want to avoid this as it may damage the FPGA. Can someone suggest me with a solution?

Schematic for reference
[image: Buffer_sch]

Comment: Not a good idea. the ESD diodes are pulling Vdd up from the input which enables an output driven by your source. The 74ALC family has 25 Ohm driver. never apply signals before power on CMOS. this can cause latch up.

Comment: Is there any way I can use the same circuitry with some modifications and make the output low till the device is powered on. Or can you suggest me any other buffer IC which suits my application.

Comment: I don’t understand your interconnections but Pwr on reset low until Vdd detected.

Comment: You say that you are using this IC to 'buffer' the signal. Exactly why are you doing this?

Comment: Thank you @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 . But there are no IOs to control the POR. And I have made the output enable signals active default.

Comment: @BruceAbbott The input to my system comes from a client device, the cable runs over a length of 1.5 meters. In order to increase the drive strength of these LVTTL signals before giving it to the FPGA, I am using this Buffer IC.

Comment: Interfacing IO signals between two IC's which are not powered up at the same time can be pretty tricky. But some buffers support it. The magic words in the data sheet, at least for TI parts are "Partial power off" or "Ioff". Datasheets that mention that are able to maintain all inputs at high impedance when VCC is not present. Also, all outputs will be high impedance and floating.

Comment: Thank you @mkeith. It is confirmed both theoretically(from datasheet) and practically(from physical observation) that this Buffer IC doesn't support the Partial power down. So I want to use an alternate IC which supports the above mentioned feature. I want to save myself with the designing time and manufacturing expenditure by finding a pin compatible IC.

Comment: Try removing the buffer and add a 100 Ohms or so in series at Tx instead to reduce the ringing from mismatched impedances.  Its not a buffer you need

Answer (score 1):

IC behaviour is usually unspecified when no power is supplied. As commented, you will try to power the whole board with your input signals in that case, due to the ESD protection diode.

There are, however special IC families that are are rated for this (for texas device look for the "Ioff partial power down" feature). Anyway I'd recommend at least a protection resistor on the inputs. Difficult to say more without the schematic.

Comment: Thank you. I have attached the snap of the schematic for reference. I havn't provided any series resistors on the input pins.

Comment: ALVC inputs do not have ESD diodes to Vcc and are overvoltage tolerant. Only at the outputs would an external voltage be a problem.

Comment: @CL. _Only at the outputs would an external voltage be a problem_ can you kindly explain this statement.

Comment: @lorenzo I want to use this IC SN74ALVTH162827 with Ioff = ±100 µA which has the same pin out of the IC I am currently using. Is Ioff = ±100 µA sufficient as I have 36 input signals to the board?

Comment: @saikumarkanikatla The inputs do not have ESD diodes to Vcc, but the outputs have them. So a voltage applied to an output (even when /OE is high) can allow a current to flow into Vcc, and thus power up the device.

Comment: @CL. In my case the power supply to the buffer IC is connected from the FPGA mother card which is in off state. So the output signals connected to the FPGA have no voltage on them. I have tested the Buffer IC alone by just applying 3.3V input signal and found 3.3V at the output and VCC pins.

Comment: @saikumarkanikatla This should not be possible, unless the device is damaged and there is a short between the input and VCC. Does it still work? Do you measure a resistance between any input and VCC?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the support. **SN74ALVTH16827** Solved my issue as it has Ioff feature, unlike SN74ALVCH16827.

Comment: saikumarkanikatla - Hi, Thanks for coming back with this update. In order to mark the topic as solved, please consider "accepting" the [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/550631) which suggested that you look for the "Ioff" feature which you used (to accept an answer, click the "tick mark" next to your answer, to turn it green). Then the question is shown as having an accepted answer in various lists, and we don't get nagged for it being a question with an unaccepted answer. Thanks!